# How to make a reverse "flatMap" operation

Tags: java, java-stream

```
List<String> flattened = Stream
                .of(Arrays.asList("aa", "bb", "cc"), Arrays.asList("ddd", "eee", "fff"), Arrays.asList("uuuuu", "vvvvv", "kkkkkk"))
                .flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(flattened);
```

Now this prints out `[aa, bb, cc, ddd, eee, fff, uuuuu, vvvvv, kkkkkk]`

**The Problem:**
How to reverse the flatMap operation? Transform this stream

```
[kkkkk, eee, uuuuu, bb, aa, vvvvv, fff, ddd, bb]
```

back into this

```
[[cc, bb, aa], [eee, fff, ddd], [kkkkk, vvvvv, uuuuu]]
```

Comment: I think you'll want to use Collectors.groupingBy to create a map which you will then be able to transform into the expected array of arrays

Comment: Objects do not have a memory of their history. A flat list is a flat list, regardless of how you created it. Therefore, it is impossible to reverse its creation process. You can group elements by some criteria, as shown by the answers, but there is no guaranty that the result matches the source lists.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to implement a `collect` operation. Java already brings a library of standardized collectors which you can use, e.g.

```
Collection<List<String>> grouped = flattened.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length))
                .values();
```

Answer (score 2):

### [List#subList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,int))

If you know the size of sublists, you can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> flattened = Stream
                .of(Arrays.asList("aa", "bb", "cc"), Arrays.asList("ddd", "eee", "fff"),
                        Arrays.asList("uuuuu", "vvvvv", "kkkkkk"))
                .flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(flattened);

        List<List<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
        final int SIZE = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < flattened.size(); i += SIZE) {
            listOfLists.add(flattened.subList(i, i + SIZE));
        }
        System.out.println(listOfLists);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[aa, bb, cc, ddd, eee, fff, uuuuu, vvvvv, kkkkkk]
[[aa, bb, cc], [ddd, eee, fff], [uuuuu, vvvvv, kkkkkk]]
```